# Google authentication with Azure functions

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-signin, azure-authentication

What im trying to accomplish is a user should login to google with my Xamarin forms app and the app should then validate the users token serverside.
So fare i have implemented the login in Xamarin with `Xamarin.Auth` and im able to get these tokens:

- access_token
- refresh_token
- id_token

As i read the documentation of the Azure functions authentication i should make a POST request and supply the id_token as client_id to https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google
in the body as JSON.

This results in a

> 400 - Invalid Client Credentials

From postman.

In Google APIS/Services i have one App with two credentials

- On for Android for my App
- On for web application for my Azure functions

I followed a guide and enabled Google authentication in my Azure function with the App id and secret.

Xamarin code:

```
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static OAuth2Authenticator Auth;
        public AuthenticatorPage AuthPage;
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                "AndroidGoogleApiIdString.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                string.Empty,
                "email",
                new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"),
                new Uri("com.companyname.AppName:/oauth2redirect"),
                new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"),
                null,
                true);

            Auth.CreateRequestQueryParameters(new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"requestServerAuthCode", "AzureFunctionGoogleAppIdString.apps.googleusercontent.com" },
                {"response_type", "code" }
            });

            AuthPage = new AuthenticatorPage(Auth);

            Auth.Completed += Auth_Completed;
            Auth.Error += Auth_Error;
        }

        ...
}
```

Azure function setup.
[image: Azure function authentication screenshot]

Comment: What documentation are you referring to? You'd need to send the ID token and authorization code, but in the code above, you don't seem to be issuing a request against Azure Functions.

Comment: I followed this tutorial for implementing the google auth in Xamarin: [Xamarin tut](https://timothelariviere.com/2017/09/01/authenticate-users-through-google-with-xamarin-auth/). I then followed this tutorial: [Azure tut](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2018/02/19/azure-functions-and-app-service-authentication/) to implement the Azure part. Then at the section: **Logging In** it says to just post the **id_token**. I later read that i need the authorization code as you say, but i don't know how to obtain it with Xamarin.Auth.